# How can I get our nginx access_log to not put a : in the timezone offset?

Tags: nginx, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

nginx outputs the correct ISO860 standard in this format:

```
2017-09-29T15:39:06+00:00
```

Which is GREAT except AWS CloudWatch only works when the : is not in the timezone offset. Like this:

```
2017-09-29T15:39:06+0000
```

We need to output a time format which CloudWatch can interpret. CloudWatch is "broken" since it uses the time functions in python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way as such. But it is possible to customize logs format and change variables. So we can use that to workout this

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {

map $time_iso8601 $time_aws {
   ~(.*):(00)  "$1$2";
}

log_format new_format '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_aws] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log /dev/stdout  new_format;
server {
   listen 80;
   location / {
      return 200 "test";
   }
}

}
```

This give me below access log

```
172.19.0.1 - - [2017-09-29T16:43:55+0000] "GET /tarun HTTP/1.1" 200 51 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

So now you just need to match the format to the way you want